# Running golang web server in background

Tags: web-services, go, service, webserver, glide-golang

What is the simplest way to run a go server in the background?
I currently have the server running in CMD and would rather not change the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a screen. Assuming Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Then

```
screen
```

Then

```
go run main.go
```

Use Ctrl + A + D to get out of the screen. To return to it:

```
screen -r
```

Comment: If using a Linux based system `systemd-run` can start transient units: `systemd-run --user go run main.go`. But I suppose he uses Windows (`CMD`)

Comment: I'm using Windows, unfortunately